# [updated]Intergrating NextJS and Redux State Management

Tags: react-redux

this my updated version of intergrating redux and NextJS. Just to elobarate what I have done so far...

STEP 1. I've created a store.js file to set up my global store in reference to github's explanation from nextJS developers.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { customerListReducer } from './customerReducers';

const bindMiddleware = (middleware) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension');
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  customerList: customerListReducer,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log('Just Displaying the Store', state);
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    };
    if (state.count) nextState.count = state.count; // preserve count value on client side navigation
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};

// create a makeStore function
const store = () =>
  createStore(
    reducer,
    bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware])
  );

// export an assembled wrapper
export const wrapper = createWrapper(store);
```

STEP 2: Imported the wrapper above in my _app file to make the wrapper available across all pages in my application

```
import Nav from '../components/Nav';
import {wrapper} from '../reducers/store';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

STEP 3: CONFIGURATIONS

A) My Action that calls external API

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  CUSTOMER_LIST_REQUEST,
  CUSTOMER_LIST_SUCCESS,
  CUSTOMER_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/customerConstants';

export const listCustomers = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: CUSTOMER_LIST_REQUEST,
    });  

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://byronochara.tech/gassystem/api/v1/customers'
    );
    const result = data.results;

    dispatch({
      type: CUSTOMER_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: result,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CUSTOMER_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

B)My Action Reducer

```
import {
  CUSTOMER_LIST_REQUEST,
  CUSTOMER_LIST_SUCCESS,
  CUSTOMER_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/customerConstants';
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

export const customerListReducer = (state = { customers: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HYDRATE:
      return { loading: true, customers: [] };
    case CUSTOMER_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, customers: [] };
    case CUSTOMER_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        customers: action.payload,
      };
    case CUSTOMER_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

C)The finally bringing it all together in my index.js page to display the results:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { listCustomers } from './../actions/customerActions';
import { wrapper } from '../reducers/store';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css';
const Home = () => {

  //Select the loaded customers' list from central state
  const customerList = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return state.customerList;
  });
  const { loading, error, customers } = customerList;
//displaying the customers data from the external API
  console.log('Fetched Customers Data', customers);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Home | Next</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>
      {/* {loading && <h6>Loading...</h6>} */}
      {/* {error && <h6>Error Occured...</h6>} */}
      {/* {customers.map((customer) => (
        <h3>{customer.customerName}</h3>
      ))} */}
      {/* <ArticleList customers={customers} /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

// getStaticProp at build time
// getServerSideProp at every request slower
// getStaticPath to dynamically generate paths based on the data we are fetching

export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async ({ store }) => {
  // console.log('STORE', store);
  store.dispatch(listCustomers());
});


export default Home;
```

COMMENT ON THE PROBLEM I'M FACING FROM THE ABOVE CODE: once everything has been set up if you follow the code above, the code seems to run well the store is successfully created when I log the result on the console ``{ customerList: { loading: true, customers: [] } }`. But then I guess this is the result from the HYDRATE action type since it will always be dispatch since am using` getStaticProps``` that creates a new store instance in the server.

MAIN QUIZ: My challenge is how do I bypass the HYDRATED action and reconcile the server side state with the client side store and persist it and at least to finally be able to view the list from the external API. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I totally recommend you to use [reduxjs/toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/). It's very simple , less code, no wrappers, clean. And no matter your project on nextjs or created via CRA. Also you dont need to configure redux-thunk and redux-devtools cause they are enabled by default. Read documentation for more information ( how to persist state without any npm package and so on )

Here is a little example.

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from './user.slice.js';

//reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

Wrap with Provider (in your case _app.js)

```
  <Provider store={store}>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Provider>
```

user.slice.js ( action + reducer )

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  id: '',
  email: '',
  roles: []
};

// export async action
export const signIn = createAsyncThunk('user/signIn', async (data) => {
  try {
    const payload = await api.auth.signin(data).then((res) => res.data);
    // do some stuff if you want 
    return payload ;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response);
  }
});
  

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    removeUser(state, payload) {
      //cant be an async method
      return initialState;
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
     builder.addCase(signIn.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
       // payload from the async method above (asyncThunk)
       return payload;
     });
   },
  },
});

// export actions
export const { removeUser } = userSlice.actions;
// export reducer
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Thats it. Last step to call actions from any component e.g.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, removeUser } from '../actions/userSlice';

  // in function component 
  // call hooks
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // read the store
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state); 

  // dispatch any action , example below
  dispatch(signIn(userCredentials));
  // or 
  dispatch(removeUser());
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it right away then I'll respond back with my feedback.

Comment: Please see the update code below with react toolkit which seems to be working with NexJS but still cannot store the data on the Globall state.

Comment: Variant D is incorrect. You used redux-thunk ( function that returns another *async* function that takes dispatch as an argument ) but with toolkit async actions implementedlittle bit different. See my example with createAsyncThunk . In your case you dont need D at all.

Comment: also leave useEffect input empty ( [dispatch] not needed, just [] )
Rest of all seems good, just create async actions and call it  with dispatch

Answer (score 0):

I has an Issue with setting Redux with NextJS and this is my final answer after some insight from `mirik999` too.

A. my store.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
//importing the slice file with sliced reducers
import customerListReducer from '../slices/customerSlice';

// const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    customerList: customerListReducer,
  },
});
export default store;
```

B. The store is provided in my app component

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Nav />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

C. The Slice file that automatically creates action creators and the reducer

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

//creating and action that calls API from a REST API backend
export const customersFetchedList = createAsyncThunk(
  'customersList/customersListSuccess',
  async () => {
    try {

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        'https://example.com/api/your/endpoint'
      );
      const result = data.results;
      //the payload
      const payload = result;
      return payload;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      const payload =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      return payload;
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  customers: [],
  error: false,
};

const customerListSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'customersList',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    //reducer functions we've provided
    customersRequest(state, action) {
      if (state.loading == true) {
        return state;
      }
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    initialState,
      builder.addCase(customersFetchedList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.customers = action.payload;
        state.error = false;
        return state;
      });
  },
});

export const {
  customersRequest,
  customersLoadingError,
} = customerListSlice.actions;

export default customerListSlice.reducer;
```

D. Then finally fired this action above in my component using the useEffect()

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

const Home = () => {
  //method to fire the action
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //Select the loaded customers' list from central state
  const customerList = useSelector((state) => state);
  // const { loading, error, customers } = customerList;

  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(listCustomers());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Home | Next</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Welcome to Home Page</h1>
      {loading && <h6>Loading...</h6>}
      {error && <h6>Error Occured...</h6>}
      {customers.map((customer) => (
        <h3>{customer.customerName}</h3>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks so much for your contribution. :)